# highstock x-axis crosshair - to appear/move on click instead of mousehover

Tags: highcharts

I am trying to customize a x-axis crosshair to appear move on `click` instead of `mouseMove` event...

As in below example i have crosshair set up,
https://jsfiddle.net/guestMe/orL5txs0/29/

An idea to attach click event on existing crosshair is using -

Access the highchart default crosshair using `this.chart.xAxis[0].cross` and then attach click event on it ...

Comment: Hi @Dreamweaver, I'm not quite sure what exactly you want to achieve. Could you describe the problem in more detail? For example in this live example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/6um4tpLd/ a tooltip and crosshair are shown only after point click and hidden on mouseOut.

Comment: Actually i wanted to check , if exsting crosshair can be modified to achevie something as blue draggable line 

https://jsfiddle.net/guestMe/orL5txs0/75/

Comment: The simplest way is to disable the default crosshair and add a custom line like in the provided example. Do you have any restrictions related to this?

Comment: I wont say restriction, but highchart has dones amazing job and many logic to place it correctly... :) so it would have be nicer to reuse it..  
For now we went ahead with having custom line :)

Comment: Yes, I agree, it has amazing and complex logic, but that's why it is easier to create a custom line than overwriting this whole logic.